# 5.1 surround sound doesn't work on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, audio, drivers, dolbydigital

I have my computer hooked up to a 5.1 surround sound system (which system it is is irrelevant) via optical cable and my computer won't play 5.1 sound.

I recently installed Windows 8 on this computer, when I was running windows 7 the 5.1 sound worked just fine and I haven't changed any settings on the sound system.

When I was running Windows 7, the screen below used to have a Dolby Digital tab where did the tab go?

[image]

There is Dolby Digital on the screen below, and when I press the Test button, all 5 speakers and the subwoofer work.

[image]

However, I can't get it to work with any actual applications. For example, [this](http://www.lynnepublishing.com/surround/www_lynnemusic_com_surround_test.ac3) 5.1 test file only plays in Stereo (tested and working in Windows 7).

Is there a driver I'm missing or a setting I need to change that I keep missing?

My computer has the Gigabyte GA-880GA-UD3H Motherboard, I'm using the onboard audio, and I'm running Windows 8 64-bit.

Comment: Have you downloaded and installed the latest drivers from the Gigabyte support page?

Comment: I looked at them and none of them had anything to do with audio. [Here](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3758#dl) is the link to its page.

Comment: The audio driver is under the Windows 7 category, doesn't look like there is one there for Windows 8. You could contact Gigabyte support or try the Windows 7 driver.

Comment: I'll try downloading and installing the Windows 7 one.  However Gigabytes' servers are really slow, only downloading at about 17kB/s so this 77MB file is gonna take an hour to download. I swear I thought we were done with dial-up.

Comment: Installing the windows 7 sound drivers worked, post an answer below with a link to the sound drivers and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like Gigabyte/Realtek have official Windows 8 drivers yet. You can download the Windows 7 drivers [here](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3758#dl) and use them.